# Plyer notification click event - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, notifications, system-tray, mouseclick-event

Not finding a way to use a system tray for my python script, I've found an easy work around with plyer, having the wanted effect with the following code :

```
from plyer import notification
notif = notification.notify(
            title='Setting system tray',
            message='Double click to show',
            app_name='To do list',
            app_icon='icone.ico',
            timeout=999999
        )
```

I've put timeout to 999999 for a 11days long system tray which I think is a good solution for my cheap trick.
However, I wanted to be able to add events linked to clicks with that icon. Is there a way to link mouse events to a plyer notification icon ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to that with plyer now, I have glanced through the source code and i dont see any implementation as such.